# Get Path of Jar file: different result for different project

Tags: java, path, jar

I have a code that take path of current jar file. But there is a strange thing: I have two jar file (two different project). at project A: when I run this and print to console, I see it print correctly.
But, at project B: it just print drive of current jar file, not till folder.

For example: both A.jar and B.jar in folder D:\temp:

result of B: `/D:/temp/`

result of A: `./` (has a dot before !!!)

Here is my code:

```
        String path = getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
        String decodedPath = URLDecoder.decode(path, "UTF-8");
        String RealPath = decodedPath.substring(0, decodedPath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

        System.out.println("path: " + path);
        System.out.println("decodePath: "+decodedPath);
        System.out.println("Real path not include file name: "+RealPath);
```

Comment: can you post the command line expression that you use to launch both the projects?

Comment: *"I have a code that take path of current jar file."*  Why?

Comment: Works correctly for me, but if you run it as a .class I don't get the expected behavior for your "RealPath".  What console/terminal are you using btw?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: because I want to generate a file that has same path with jar file.

Comment: @YoussefG. i use command prompt of windows 7 I think no problem here !

Comment: **Don't do that.**  It will never work for an applet or JWS app. and OS makers have long been saying that the place the app. is installed is not necessarily the place to put 'program options'.  Put the data in a sub-directory of `user.home` and be done with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, when I was working with directories in java the full stop ( . ) means the current directory. Possibly it could be just java acting weirdly? Or are you running both jars simultaneously? Try running A before B or vice-versa, and see if it makes a different. (I would make this as a comment but I don't think I have enough reputation to do so :( )